# SSIS in VS 2017 returns error on SQL Task

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

This is weird. On any SQL Task regardless of ADO.NET or OLEDB connection. Run debug and get The Execute method on the task returned error code 0x80070002 
(Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, blah-blah

Comment: Try re-installing Visual Studio.   Sounds like yours is corrupted/missing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tab 
Think I found it. Had to look real close in the GAC. The error message was right on the money. I had to hunt down MS SqlServer 2016 Feature Pack - a kitchen sink download that included ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi. Good old MS. They never make it easy, do they.